Import Excel file into my database using Laravel Application
I'm working on a Laravel V9.0 application where I need to import user data from an Excel file into a PostgreSQL database. I have set up the import functionality using the Maatwebsite Excel package. However, when I submit the form to upload the file, it redirects me to the default page of Laravel application, and I don't see any import results or error messages(When im using Postman).
When i use blade.php view it returns Users imported successfully!.When i check the table in my postgresql i find it either empty or only one instance and it is null.
//UsersController.php:

public function importUsers(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,csv'
        ]);

        Excel::import(new UsersImport, $request->file('file'));

        return back()->with('success', 'Users imported successfully!');
    }

//UsersImport.php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            if (empty($row['Matricule'])) {
                continue; 
            }

            User::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'matricule' => $row['Matricule'],
                ],
                [
                    'id_badge' => $row['Badge'] ?? null,
                    'nom' => $row['Nom'] ?? null,
                    'prenom' => $row['Prenom'] ?? null,
                    'post' => $row['Departement'] ?? null,
                    'role' => $row['Role'] ?? '1',
                    'id_projet' => $row['Project Id'] ?? null, 
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}

//migration table for users:

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_projet');
            $table->integer('id_badge')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('matricule');
            $table->string('nom')->nullable();
            $table->string('prenom')->nullable();
            $table->string('post')->nullable();
            $table->enum('role',['0','1'])->default('1')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('id_projet')->references('id')->on('projects');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Route::post('/import-users', [UsersController::class, 'importUsers'])->name('import.users');

//excel form:
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/rfItZBkZ.png)


Have you checked your logs? Are there any errors there? Also, are all of your fields in User model fillable (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)?

yes i used logs and it says it was filled successfully and when I check the database i find the database not filled.
And i know the problem is not from the connection with the database because i already worked with plenty of methods that includes the database

please post the full UsersImport class and not just the collection method.
